# IBM x3550 Unrecognised progress code

Tags: ibm-xseries

I have an x3550 M4 in our lab that will not boot past the 'System Initializing...' message. This happened after a power loss. I unplugged for an extended period and have removed/reseated the two different kinds of memory and each of the two CPUs one at a time and an installed memory cache. One thing I'm noticing is the 'Light Path Diagnostics' panel never lights at all where normally a blue 'i' light, only the green power light on the panel works fine. I did push the reset button. The panel cable does have a crease in one spot where rubbed against the frame, but does not look cut.

The memory cache has lit green light. The four board lights behind the power supply show solid green for `PWR`, slow blinking green light for `RTMM Heartbeat`, a rapid blinking green light for `IMM2 Heartbeat` while connected cable to IMM2 port not lit and no light on `SYS BRD ERR` light. The IMM2 is configured and not responding. The error displayed is:

```
(0x 2) Unrecognised progress code
```

What would be my next steps to diagnose this issue? I cannot seem to find an official diagnostics CD or other downloads.

Answer (score 2):

Forgot about the CMOS battery. After pulling for several minutes and put back, the system is booting. All okay.